# heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" | Error occurs when deployed in Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I am currently taking the MERN stack e-commerce course from Brad and Bassir in Udemy. When I deployed in Heroku, I got this error. I don't know how to resolve it.

These are the logs when I run heroku logs --tail command

```
2021-10-15T17:50:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user roopeshsaravanan.dev@gmail.com
2021-10-15T17:53:37.636364+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 90321645 by user roopeshsaravanan.dev@gmail.com
2021-10-15T17:53:37.636364+00:00 app[api]: Release v19 created by user roopeshsaravanan.dev@gmail.com
2021-10-15T17:53:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-10-15T17:53:43.122703+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-10-15T17:53:50.219102+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node backend/server.js`
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386374+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386389+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386390+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386390+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386390+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'nodemon'
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386390+00:00 app[web.1]: Require stack:
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386391+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/models/userModel.js
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386391+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/middleware/authMiddleware.js
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386391+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/routes/productRoutes.js
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386391+00:00 app[web.1]: - /app/backend/server.js
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386392+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386393+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/models/userModel.js:4:19)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386393+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386394+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386394+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386394+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386395+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386395+00:00 app[web.1]: requireStack: [
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386395+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/models/userModel.js',
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386395+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/middleware/authMiddleware.js',
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386396+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/routes/productRoutes.js',
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386396+00:00 app[web.1]: '/app/backend/server.js'
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386396+00:00 app[web.1]: ]
2021-10-15T17:53:51.386396+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-10-15T17:53:51.503588+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-10-15T17:53:51.589143+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-10-15T17:54:14.240609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=9000e675-5c48-4ef5-bcd0-9e968668542a fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-15T17:54:16.260707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=d645168d-e122-435d-bd5f-2634f6a66f28 fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-15T17:54:24.212721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=35ab40a6-e42d-4b54-83a1-9b5526929d38 fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-15T17:54:25.252707+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=65c7660f-9c13-42af-92f3-f358830bb993 fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-15T18:16:35.058685+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=e3380719-6b36-4db6-a705-e1ea7eea88dc fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-10-15T18:16:36.046104+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=largegreen.herokuapp.com request_id=6dd2cf7e-ca8c-481a-94b6-70f3ed0d3683 fwd="42.111.162.194" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: Please refer to my response to prevent any errors, This error could occur when you have not used `proxy` in `package.json`.

Comment: error: Cannot find module 'nodemon'. Just install nodemon, or make it a dev dependancy

Comment: Let me know if this solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

### **1. Try to set up this type of directory Structure**

```
|__client/  THIS IS EVERYTHING FROM THE REACT SIDE 
    |__ node_modules/
        |__ tons of stuff...
    |__ public/
        |__ index.html
        |__ favicon.ico
        |__ etc.
    |__ src/
        |__ index.js
        |__ main/
            |__ App.js
            |__ etc.
|__ models/
    |__ user.js
    |__ todo.js
    |__ etc.
|__ node_modules/
    |__ stuff...
|__ routes
    |__ userRoutes.js
    |__ todoRoutes.js
    |__ etc.
|__ .gitignore
|__ package.json
|__ server.js
|__ etc.
```

### **2. Add this Middleware**

```
// ... Other imports
const path = require("path");

// Other app.use middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));

// Right before your app.listen(), add this:
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(...);
```

### **3. Add a proxy to the client's `package.json`**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

So, your `package.json` file looks like...

```
{
    "name": "client",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.17.1",
        "react": "^16.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
}
```

### **4. Setting environment variables on the website:**

```
A. Open your app in Heroku
B. Go to "Settings"
C. Click "Reveal Config Vars"
D. Add a new variable and click "Add". Done!
E. Your port has to look like:- process.env.PORT || 8000
```

Your Port looks like this:-

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
.
.
.
app.listen(port);
```

### **5. Set up MongoDB Atlas IP access control**

Next, you'll need to whitelist your IP address so that you can access your cluster. Go to Network Access on the navigation menu, and Add IP Address. You can either Add Your Current IP Address or **Allow Access from Anywhere**. **Confirm** your choice.

For any projects deployed through Heroku, you'll have to select Allow Access from Anywhere. This is because Heroku uses Dynamic IPs. While this isn't the most secure option, it is fine for now.

### **6. Add this scripts `start` `heroku-postbuild` and `engines`**

After all this, your server's `package.json` should look something like this:
In the terminal, type `node -v`. It should spit out the version of Node.js you're using. add this version in the `"engines": "14.17.5"`

```
{
    "name": "mern-to-heroku",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "server.js",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "express": "^4.16.2",
        "mongoose": "^4.13.6",
        "morgan": "^1.9.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install --only=dev && npm install && npm run build"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "14.17.5"
    }
}
```

## You should now be all set up to deploy your site through Heroku!

Comment: Thanks, Smit Gajera for your solution. Really learned a lot from your post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy be myself and got the same error.
Make the port dynamic (most likely **process.env.PORT**) and set the correct run command **web: npm run start:prod**

Source and more info:
https://dev.to/rosyshrestha/deploy-nestjs-typescript-app-to-heroku-27e